# How can I make a while loop inside another while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a quiz system. Here is my form for fetching all questions from a databse:

```
  <form method="POST">
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM quiz";
      $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {

      ?>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $rows['question']?></h4><hr style="margin-bottom: -25px;">
            <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="la la-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>

          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">


                 <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input form-control" name="customRadio" id="customRadio1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1"><?php echo $rows['option2']?></label>
               </div>

               <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input form-control" name="customRadio" id="customRadio2">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2"><?php echo $rows['option2']?></label>
               </div>

               <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input form-control" name="customRadio" id="customRadio3">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio3"><?php echo $rows['option3']?></label>
               </div>

               <div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input form-control" name="customRadio" id="customRadio4">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio4"><?php echo $rows['option4']?></label>
               </div>

            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
      <?php

      }


      ?>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

The radio button works only when ID and For Attr have same value
and this should be different for all questions. Like

- for 1st question it should be:

  - name: customRadio1
  - for: customRadio1
- and 2nd:

  - name: customRadio2
  - for: customRadio2
    And so on. How can i achieve that??

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your `<input>` into `<label>` to achieve the same effect without ids.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio form-group">
    <label class="custom-control-label">
        <?php echo $rows['option3']?>
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input form-control" name="customRadio">
    </label>
</div>
```